# Google Material Design mdl-layout__drawer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, material-design-lite

I have looked everywhere from Google's website to http://materialdesignblog.com/ and even on here, but I am not having any luck.

I will note, that this is my first Google Material design/site. Up til now, I have been using bootstrap.

I have a design in mind (see picture below) that I would like achieve.

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

I understand that this may seem like a question that may be simple to work out, but I am wondering if maybe I should use a bootstrap + material, I am sure what I am asking is do-able

the look I am trying to get is

[image: content/uploads/2015/06/fb_material_design_01-2-2.png]

Comment: Material Design is a concept of design developed by Google. You can use any framework or platform you so choose to create that style. I think your note regarding header/footer and infinite scroll are another question all together.

Comment: @EoghanTadhg So let's just target one thing than how do I get the float navigation?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too vague. Consider asking a new question with a specific example of what you are trying to accomplish.